# Why this python code is showing error to check a palindrome no.?

Tags: python-3.x

Whenever I run is_palindrome('otto'), it shows the error 'IndexError: string index out of range'...However,when I just compile the code, it does not show any error as such. thanks for helping out

```
def middle(word):    
   return word[1:-1]

def is_palindrome(word):
  if word[0] != word[-1]:
    return False
  elif len(word)<=1:
    return True
  else:    
    return is_palindrome(middle(word))
```

Comment: Please add the error text, and stack trace if applicable.

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: Coder: You should edit your question and add that to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is happening is that for strings of even numbers of chars, it will eventually run palindrome("") which throws an out of bounds error. Try switching `len(word)<=1` and `word[0] != word[-1]`

Comment: Thanks Phonzi..it's working now..but can you plz explain in detail your point of view on out of bounds error..Grateful for helping..thanks!!

Comment: @Coder Certainly, there are many resources that can explain it better, but in general, you can think of an out of bounds error as trying to call a part of a list or string that doesn't exist. For example, if you were to call for the third character of a string that only has 1 character, you would get an out of bounds exception. In this case, your code originally would end up trying to find the second character through the second to last character of an empty string. Therefore, those characters did not exist, and you got an exception. Again, there are many resources that could explain it better